# CSS - button element rollover (not anchor element)

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-6, hover

I know how to use background images and their position on an anchor element (using :hover). It's my understanding that ie6 doesn't support `button:hover`. How can I achieve this effect using only css?

Comment: Just a comment: It's not worth your time worrying about IE6 compatibility these days. If a user is using IE6, I doubt they are even interested in seeing a hover effect.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you mention you know that IE6 doesn't support it to say that you don't care if it supports it, or to indicate that you are looking for a way to do it in IE6?

Answer (score 2):

IE6 only supports the :hover pseudo class on anchor elements.  That means, just like everything else, you have to get a bit creative if you want to achieve this effect.

You'd possibly achieve a hack of this by starting with using conditional comments to include an IE6-specific style sheet for your page / site.

You could then either use a background image that looks the same as your button's background and set an anchor tag to use that background image with the image's correct fixed width, or (untested so not sure about this one) try wrapping the button in an anchor tag.